# GD library Showing Special Characters

Tags: php, laravel, gd

I have GD library installed as you can see.(image)
but when i try to create a image it shows special characters instead of the image.(image)
I'm using laravel and Xampp.

Anyone Know what is the problem ?

```
<?php
  

// create a blank image
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 300);

// fill the background color
$bg = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

// choose a color for the ellipse
$col_ellipse = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

// draw the white ellipse
imagefilledellipse($image, 200, 150, 300, 200, $col_ellipse);

// output the picture
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image); ?>
```

[image]

Comment: The output (in the image) looks like a `var_dump`, not the output of that script. (Those "special characters" _are_ your image)

Comment: I know that is my image , but why is showing like that ? it must be something with laravel , because i've tested on a clean index.php and worked , but inside a laravel view it does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to show as an image, you need to remove any output before sending a `header`. Remove `var_dump(gd_info());` from your code to see the actual image:

```
<?php

// create a blank image
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(400, 300);

// fill the background color
$bg = imagecolorallocate($image, 0, 0, 0);

// choose a color for the ellipse
$col_ellipse = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

// draw the white ellipse
imagefilledellipse($image, 200, 150, 300, 200, $col_ellipse);

// output the picture
header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($image); ?>
```

From https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php:

"*Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent*"

Comment: that's exactly how my code is ,i use the var dump just to show my gd library,  as i told you it must be something with laravel , because it is not accepting the header("Content-type: image/png");

Comment: That's _not_ exactly how your code is, you have that `var_dump` in there. If that `var_dump` is not relevant to your problem/code, please remove it. How do you call/access that image?

Comment: I have a function in my controller  public function image()


    {

        return View('image');
    }
and the code is my view "image.blade.php"

Comment: That's not how it works. When using a blade view content has already been sent and thus `header` won't work. If that script was in a separate `.php` script (say `image.php`) you'd access the image using `<img src="image.php">`.

Comment: i just figured out , in my function  i returned a response with the view and the header         return response()
            ->view('image')
            ->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');
thanks for the help btw